# C# yield return performance

Tags: c#, memory, return, yield

How much space is reserved to the underlying collection behind a method using yield return syntax WHEN I PERFORM a ToList() on it? There's a chance it will reallocate and thus decrease performance if compared to the standard approach where i create a list with predefined capacity?

The two scenarios:

```
    public IEnumerable<T> GetList1()
    {
        foreach( var item in collection )
            yield return item.Property;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetList2()
    {
        List<T> outputList = new List<T>( collection.Count() );
        foreach( var item in collection )
            outputList.Add( item.Property );

        return outputList;
    }
```

Comment: What example can you provide, or indicator that suggest there is a deviation between the two?  We won't do all the work, we require a basic underlying example.

Comment: What collection? `yield return` generates an enumerator - there's no storage.

Comment: @Chris There is storage, but for maintaining the enumerator state alone. But yes no collection as OP seems to be saying.

Comment: Let's say i ToList(). Reallocation can occur?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Hehe yes I suppose there is some storage if we consider that part!

Comment: To answer your new question (about ToList()), it'll do the exact same thing as the other version. As you can see [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,e276d6892241255b), `ToList` simply instantiates a new List.

Comment: Reallocation of what?

Comment: I'd question "standard approach". If anything is "standard" here, it's the first of your examples, not the second one.

Comment: @SolalPirelli the constructor of `List<T>` is optimised for receiving an `ICollection<T>` though. That said, the difference in what that optimisation does is **exactly** the same as the pessimisation that `GetList2` here has in being deliberately slower and heavier on memory than `GetList1`, so it balances out.

Answer (score 22):

`yield return` does not create an array that has to be resized, like what `List` does; instead, it creates an `IEnumerable` with a state machine.

For instance, let's take this method:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Foo()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Returning 1");
    yield return 1;
    Console.WriteLine("Returning 2");
    yield return 2;
    Console.WriteLine("Returning 3");
    yield return 3;
}
```

Now let's call it and assign that enumerable to a variable:

```
var elems = Foo();
```

**None** of the code in `Foo` has executed yet. Nothing will be printed on the console. But if we iterate over it, like this:

```
foreach(var elem in elems)
{
    Console.WriteLine( "Got " + elem );
}
```

On the first iteration of the `foreach` loop, the `Foo` method will be executed until the first `yield return`. Then, on the second iteration, the method will "resume" from where it left off (right after the `yield return 1`), and execute until the next `yield return`. Same for all subsequent elements.
At the end of the loop, the console will look like this:

```
Returning 1
Got 1
Returning 2
Got 2
Returning 3
Got 3
```

This means you can write methods like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetAnswers()
{
    while( true )
    {
        yield return 42;
    }
}
```

You can call the `GetAnswers` method, and every time you request an element, it'll give you 42; the sequence never ends. You couldn't do this with a `List`, because lists have to have a finite size.

Answer (score 13):

> How much space is reserved to the underlying collection behind a method using yield return syntax?

There's no underlying collection.

There's an object, but it isn't a collection. Just how much space it will take up depends on what it needs to keep track of.

> There's a chance it will reallocate

No.

> And thus decrease performance if compared to the standard approach where i create a list with predefined capacity?

It will almost certainly take up less memory than creating a list with a predefined capacity.

Let's try a manual example. Say we had the following code:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> CountToTen()
{
  for(var i = 1; i != 11; ++i)
    yield return i;
}
```

To `foreach` through this will iterate through the numbers `1` to `10` inclusive.

Now let's do this the way we would have to if `yield` did not exist. We'd do something like:

```
private class CountToTenEnumerator : IEnumerator<int>
{
  private int _current;
  public int Current
  {
    get
    {
      if(_current == 0)
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
      return _current;
    }
  }
  object IEnumerator.Current
  {
    get { return Current; }
  }
  public bool MoveNext()
  {
    if(_current == 10)
      return false;
    _current++;
    return true;
  }
  public void Reset()
  {
    throw new NotSupportedException();
    // We *could* just set _current back, but the object produced by
    // yield won't do that, so we'll match that.
  }
  public void Dispose()
  {
  }
}
private class CountToTenEnumerable : IEnumerable<int>
{
  public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
  {
    return new CountToTenEnumerator();
  }
  IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
  {
    return GetEnumerator();
  }
}
public static IEnumerable<int> CountToTen()
{
  return new CountToTenEnumerable();
}
```

Now, for a variety of reasons this is quite different to the code you're likely to get from the version using `yield`, but the basic principle is the same. As you can see there are two allocations involved of objects (same number as if we had a collection and then did a `foreach` on that) and the storage of a single int. In practice we can expect `yield` to store a few more bytes than that, but not a lot.

Edit: `yield` actually does a trick where the first `GetEnumerator()` call on the same thread that obtained the object returns that same object, doing double service for both cases. Since this covers over 99% of use cases `yield` actually does one allocation rather than two.

Now let's look at:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetList1()
{
  foreach( var item in collection )
    yield return item.Property;
}
```

While this would result in more memory used than just `return collection`, it won't result in a lot more; the only thing the enumerator produced really needs to keep track of is the enumerator produced by calling `GetEnumerator()` on `collection` and then wrapping that.

This is going to be massively less memory than that of the wasteful second approach you mention, and much faster to get going.

Edit:

You've changed your question to include "syntax WHEN I PERFORM a ToList() on it", which is worth considering.

Now, here we need to add a third possibility: Knowledge of the collection's size.

Here, there is the possibilty that using `new List(capacity)` will prevent allocations of the list being built. That can indeed be a considerable saving.

If the object that has `ToList` called on it implements `ICollection<T>` then `ToList` will end up first doing a single allocation of an internal array of `T` and then calling `ICollection<T>.CopyTo()`.

This would mean that your `GetList2` would result in a faster `ToList()` than your `GetList1`.

However, your `GetList2` has already wasted time and memory doing what `ToList()` will do with the results of `GetList1` anyway!

What it should have done here was just `return new List<T>(collection);` and be done with it.

If though we need to actually **do** something inside `GetList1` or `GetList2` (e.g. convert elements, filter elements, track averages, and so on) then `GetList1` is going to be faster and lighter on memory. Much lighter if we never call `ToList()` on it, and slightly ligher if we do call `ToList()` because again, the faster and lighter `ToList()` is offset by `GetList2` being slower and heavier in the first place by exactly the same amount.